# My Middleware redirects to home page everytime

Tags: laravel

I have made a quiz when the user unlocks the quiz then only the user can access the quiz page suppose 127.0.0.1:8000/quiz1. But I have unlocked the quiz, then too my middleware takes me to /home page.

I have tried this logic but it didn't worked.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App\Theme_User;
use App\User;
use Auth;

class UnlockMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = auth()->user()->id;
        $theme_user =  Theme_User::find($user);
        if($theme_user->unlocked == 1){
        return $next($request);
        } 
        else {
            return redirect('/login');
        }
    }
}
```

In my Theme_User there is user_id and unlocked stored but that is not working for me.

Comment: Are you logged in? Because generally redirecting to /login will boot you to the defined redirectUrl in the login controller if you are already logged in.

Comment: Yes I am logged in, if I am logged out it shows me trying to get property of non object

Comment: The id, right? If you are not logged in, `auth()->user()` will be null/false/whatever and thus have no `id` property

Comment: `if(\Auth::check()) ` is your friend here...

Comment: Yes so it gives me error, but when I am logged in it redirects me to home page everytime

Comment: Can you make it as an answer? please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if they are logged in first, like so with `\Auth::check()`...

```
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(\Auth::check()) {
        $user = \Auth::user()->id;
        $theme_user =  Theme_User::find($user);
        if($theme_user->unlocked == 1){
            return $next($request);
        }
        // Logged in but not unlocked
    } 
    else {
        return redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

I have no idea what the logic is meant to be behind logged in but not unlocked, you'll need to fill that gap

Comment: The logic is that the user have to buy the quiz so as the pays us then our quiz gets unlocked

Comment: @UmarQureshi Ok so fill that gap with this logic. `return redirect(// somewhere)`

Comment: Can you assist me like return $next($request); is a route for me

Comment: That's not a great idea.`return $next($request);` will pass through the user to the callback `$next`. You would want to basically call it a fail and redirect elsewhere. Middleware is pass/reject only. No real middle ground which is I think what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth checking if user is logged in before trying to get user id from auth.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
       if(auth()->check()) { 
        $user = auth()->user()->id;
        $theme_user =  Theme_User::find($user);
        if($theme_user->unlocked == 1){
        return $next($request);
        }else{
             return redirect('whatever_page_if_user_is_logged_in_but_not_unlocked');
        } 
          }else {
//this only happens if user is not logged in
            return redirect('/login');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Amazing. Literally the exact same as mine.

Comment: sorry. posted same time maybe?